# Magento SQL error from Admin Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: mysql, magento, pdo

Dear guys I'm getting this error in Magento 1.7.0.2 from the admin page when the page takes too long to load, it never happened before this week could you help me troubleshooting this?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General        error: 1205 Lock wait timeout
>   exceeded; try restarting transaction' in
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `mg_core...', Array) 
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE`mg_core...', Array) 
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `mg in
>   /home/erboris1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and it it was related to this non-bug: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=10966 With a lot of categories, the refresh of the top-menu can use a lot of mysql ressources, because it is cached for each unique page. Our fix was to invalidate the cache only under certain circumstances.